# Multiple variables from text file in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I am writing a script to RSH into servers from a text file and create a specific user on each system. I work for a university that is currently testing Amazon EC2 for their courses. Is it possible to take colon or comma separated values in a text file like this :

```
    server.edu:user123:John:email@university.edu
```

and pass them to a BASH script as $server $username etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it like this:

```
> s='server.edu:user123:John:email@university.edu'
> IFS=: read server username email <<< "$s"

> echo "$server"
server.edu
> echo "$username"
user123
> echo "$email"
John:email@university.edu
```

**EDIT::** For reading this data from file *line by line*

```
while IFS=: read server username email; do
   echo "$server"
   echo "$username"
   echo "$email"
done < file
```

Comment: +1 But please add the `< file` variant also, to illustrate how to read this data from a file as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read lines of colon-separated data from file into an array directly and index into it:

```
while IFS=: read -a userdata; do
    printf "server: %s\n"   "${userdata[0]}"
    printf "username: %s\n" "${userdata[1]}"
    printf "name: %s\n"     "${userdata[2]}"
    printf "email: %s\n"    "${userdata[3]}"
done < data_file
```